How do I implement putchar in C to support RTS?
I'm implementing a minimal Ada RTS for the esp32s3 SoC. Currently, I am stuck with an error that's proving resistant to every solution I've thrown at it. It claims putchar is undefined:
Link
   [link]         blinky.adb
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.42
  Supported emulations:
   elf32xtensa
blinky.o
b__blinky.o
/Users/joe/Development/Ada_Xtensa_ESP32/esp32s3_hal/lib/libEsp32s3_Hal.a
/Users/joe/Development/Ada_Xtensa_ESP32/light_xtensa_esp/adalib/libgnat.a
/Users/joe/.local/share/alire/builds/hal_0.3.1_58bb6bd7/8772a4cbfba2091702a44c6fad50eea0509f0fc415885a6c2d23a26ec134eb8a/lib/libhal.a
/Users/joe/Development/Ada_Xtensa_ESP32/light_xtensa_esp/adalib/libgnat.a
/Users/joe/.local/share/alire/toolchains/gnat_xtensa_esp32_elf_14.2.1_c70145cf/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/14.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld: /Users/joe/Development/Ada_Xtensa_ESP32/light_xtensa_esp/adalib/libgnat.a(s-textio.o): in function `system__text_io__put':
s-textio.adb:(.text.system__text_io__put+0x6): undefined reference to `putchar'

However, when I implement putchar, it complains with the error:
   [C]            main.c
/Users/Joe/Development/Ada_Xtensa_ESP32/esp32s3_hal/src/main.c:12:6: error: conflicting types for built-in function 'putchar'; expected 'int(int)' [-Werror=builtin-declaration-mismatch]
   12 | void putchar(int c)

I've tried to undefined putchar and I even added -fno-builtin GCC option and I still get the same error.

   [C]            main.c
/Users/Joe/Development/Ada_Xtensa_ESP32/esp32s3_hal/src/main.c:12:6: error: conflicting types for built-in function 'putchar'; expected 'int(int)' [-Werror=builtin-declaration-mismatch]
   12 | void putchar(int c)

Over to the right of that message it says
error: conflicting types for built-in function 'putchar';
   expected 'int(int)'

so I think you should try int putchar(int c).

I tried that one and it didn't work either.  libgnat.a(s-textio.o): in function system__text_io__put': s-textio.adb:(.text.system__text_io__put+0x6): undefined reference to putchar'

First, you could use nm (for the xtensa compiler, xtensa-xxx-nm) to compare the putchar that’s in libgnat.a with the one in your attempted implementation.
Second, libgnat.a is normally called in quite late in the link, and if  the .o with your putchar comes earlier in the link order and isn’t otherwise referenced it might get ignored?

you might be able to work around this link order problem if you call putchar from main already
